# Event signal is emmitted twice every time

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

I am working on GUI appplication. From main window I open new popup window Dialog=myDialog()
(so both are now open). If i press button on that new popup window, and catch signal with this code:

```
class Ui_DialogCalibration(object):
def setupUi(self, DialogCalibration):
    DialogCalibration.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("DialogCalibration"))
    DialogCalibration.resize(888, 378)
    self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(DialogCalibration)
    self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 641, 144))
    self.widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("widget"))
    self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
    self.horizontalLayout_5.setMargin(0)
    self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_5"))
    self.radioButtonManual = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.widget)
    self.radioButtonManual.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButtonManual"))
    self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.radioButtonManual)
    self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
    self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_4"))
    self.verticalLayout_4 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_4"))
    self.pushButtonDesnoX = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
    self.pushButtonDesnoX.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButtonDesnoX"))
    self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButtonDesnoX)
    self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
    self.lineEdit.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
    self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
    self.pushButtonLijevoX = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
    self.pushButtonLijevoX.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButtonLijevoX"))
    self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButtonLijevoX)
    self.horizontalLayout_4.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_4)
    self.verticalLayout_3 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_3"))
    self.pushButtonDesnoY = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
    self.pushButtonDesnoY.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButtonDesnoY"))
    self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButtonDesnoY)
    self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
    self.lineEdit_2.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))
    self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
    self.pushButtonLijevoY = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
    self.pushButtonLijevoY.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButtonLijevoY"))
    self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButtonLijevoY)
    self.horizontalLayout_4.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)
    self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
    self.pushButtonDesnoZ = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
    self.pushButtonDesnoZ.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButtonDesnoZ"))
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButtonDesnoZ)
    self.lineEdit_3 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
    self.lineEdit_3.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_3"))
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3)
    self.pushButtoLijevoZ = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
    self.pushButtoLijevoZ.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButtoLijevoZ"))
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButtoLijevoZ)
    self.horizontalLayout_4.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
    self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
    self.pushButtonSondaSettings = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
    self.pushButtonSondaSettings.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButtonSondaSettings"))
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButtonSondaSettings)
    self.pushButtonReset = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
    self.pushButtonReset.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButtonReset"))
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButtonReset)
    self.horizontalLayout_5.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
    self.verticalLayout_5 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_5"))
    self.labelPozition = QtGui.QLabel(self.widget)
    self.labelPozition.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("labelPozition"))
    self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.labelPozition)
    self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
    self.labelpozitionX = QtGui.QLabel(self.widget)
    self.labelpozitionX.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("labelpozitionX"))
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.labelpozitionX)
    self.lineEditPozitionX = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
    self.lineEditPozitionX.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEditPozitionX"))
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEditPozitionX)
    self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
    self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"))
    self.labelPozitionY = QtGui.QLabel(self.widget)
    self.labelPozitionY.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("labelPozitionY"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.labelPozitionY)
    self.lineEditPozitionY = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
    self.lineEditPozitionY.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEditPozitionY"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEditPozitionY)
    self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
    self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_3"))
    self.labelPozitionZ = QtGui.QLabel(self.widget)
    self.labelPozitionZ.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("labelPozitionZ"))
    self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.labelPozitionZ)
    self.lineEditPozitionZ = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
    self.lineEditPozitionZ.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEditPozitionZ"))
    self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEditPozitionZ)
    self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
    self.horizontalLayout_5.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_5)
    self.widget1 = QtGui.QWidget(DialogCalibration)
    self.widget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 631, 91))
    self.widget1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("widget1"))
    self.verticalLayout_6 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.widget1)
    self.verticalLayout_6.setMargin(0)
    self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_6"))
    self.radioButtonAutomatic = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.widget1)
    self.radioButtonAutomatic.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButtonAutomatic"))
    self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButtonAutomatic)
    self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(self.widget1)
    self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
    self.buttonBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonBox"))
    self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.buttonBox)
    self.labelpozitionX.setBuddy(self.lineEditPozitionX)
    self.labelPozitionY.setBuddy(self.lineEditPozitionY)
    self.labelPozitionZ.setBuddy(self.lineEditPozitionZ)
    self.radioButtonManual.toggle()
    self.buttonBox.setEnabled(False)
    self.pushButtonDesnoX.setEnabled(False)
    self.pushButtonDesnoY.setEnabled(False)
    self.pushButtonDesnoZ.setEnabled(False)
    self.pushButtonLijevoX.setEnabled(False)
    self.pushButtonLijevoY.setEnabled(False)
    self.pushButtoLijevoZ.setEnabled(False)
    self.pushButtonReset.setEnabled(False)
    self.lineEdit.setText("1")
    self.lineEdit_2.setText("1")
    self.lineEdit_3.setText("1")
    self.X=None
    self.Y=None
    self.Z=None

    self.retranslateUi(DialogCalibration)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("accepted()")), DialogCalibration.accept)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("rejected()")), DialogCalibration.reject)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(DialogCalibration)

 class myDialog(QtGui.QDialog,Ui_DialogCalibration):
def __init__(self,sonda, parent=None):
    super(myDialog, self).__init__( parent)
    self.toupleSonda=sonda
    self.setupUi(self)
def on_pushButtonDesnoX_clicked(self):

    value=int(self.lineEdit.text())
    self.X=self.X+value
    print self.X

def retranslateUi(self, DialogCalibration):
    DialogCalibration.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("DialogCalibration", "Calibration", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.radioButtonManual.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("DialogCalibration", "manual", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButtonDesnoX.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("DialogCalibration", "Desno X", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButtonLijevoX.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("DialogCalibration", "Lijevo X", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButtonDesnoY.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("DialogCalibration", "Naprijed Y", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButtonLijevoY.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("DialogCalibration", "Nazad Y", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButtonDesnoZ.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("DialogCalibration", "Gore Z", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButtoLijevoZ.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("DialogCalibration", "Dolje Z", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButtonSondaSettings.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("DialogCalibration", "Load", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButtonReset.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("DialogCalibration", "Reset", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.labelPozition.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("DialogCalibration", "Current pozition", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.labelpozitionX.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("DialogCalibration", "X", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.labelPozitionY.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("DialogCalibration", "Y", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.labelPozitionZ.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("DialogCalibration", "Z", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.radioButtonAutomatic.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("DialogCalibration", "automatic", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

I got this oouput

1

2

So, this method has been executed twice. How can i fix this problem?
Same happens on every other signal emmitted on popup window

Comment: Please post a complete runnable code demonstrating the issue. It's not possible to understand the problem from what you have shown.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quoting from the [docs](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html#connecting-slots-by-name):

> [Connecting the both variations of the signal] also happens with signals that take optional arguments. Qt
>   implements this using multiple signals. For example,
>   `QtGui.QAbstractButton` has the following signal:
>
> ```
> void clicked(bool checked = false);
> ```
>
> Qt implements this as the following:
>
> ```
> void clicked(); 
> void clicked(bool checked);
> ```
>
> The `pyqtSlot()` decorator can be used to specify which of the signals
>   should be connected to the slot.

So your issue comes from the fact that `clicked` signal of a `QPushButton` has two overloads. Since Qt can connect signals to slots with less arguments, `connectSlotsByName` can successfully connect both overloads to your slot, thus calling the slot twice for each click.

You need to specify the appropriate overload by `pyqtSlot`:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot() # signal with no arguments
def on_pushButtonDesnoX_clicked(self):
    value=int(self.lineEdit.text())
    self.X=self.X+value
    print self.X
```

Comment: I found `@QtCore.pyqtSignature("")` is another way to specify the appropriate overload.

Comment: before adding `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()`, in my case, the signal is called three times. After adding `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()`, it's called twice. What's that two `signals`? Or, maybe it's because I'm using `pyqt5`?

Comment: @MasBagol a little late but may be important for users who face the same problem. In my case it was the "Auto connect by name" feature in setupUi() which caused to execute the signal twice. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40948706/2045142